# Nest an object's parent

Tags: css, less

I'm trying to generate some css that targets elements which have a differently named parent but a commonly named child. For example:

```
.icon-Part > .km-icon:before {
    content: "\e600";
}
.icon-Time > .km-icon:before {
    content: "\e601";
}
.icon-Error > .km-icon:before {
    content: "\e602";
}
```

Obviously if my situation were reversed and my aim was to generate css where the parents were commonly named but the child name differed I'd do something like this:

```
.parent-class {
    > .child1-class {
       /* child1 specific styling */
    }
    > .child2-class {
       /* child2 specific styling */
    }
}
```

But I can't think of any way of doing the opposite. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Parent Selectors](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature-changing-selector-order). For example like this:

```
.km-icon:before {
    .icon-Part  > & {content: "\e600"}
    .icon-Time  > & {content: "\e601"}
    .icon-Error > & {content: "\e602"}
}
```

Alternatively you can move the duplicating parts into a mixin, e.g.:

```
.icon(Part,  e600);
.icon(Time,  e601);
.icon(Error, e602);

.icon(@name, @char) {
    .icon-@{name} > 
        .km-icon:before {content: "\@{char}"}
}
```

(In fact the mixin method is more future proof.)